# Polymorphic variants and variance

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, variance

I am attempting to create a procedural object language system in OCaml. The general idea is to store values of polymoprhic variants in an array and let procedures update this array (imperatively):

```
module StrMap = Map.Make(String) 

module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)

(* store generic labeled objects *)
type 'a env = ([> ] as 'a) IntMap.t

(* a procedure working on such an object array *)
type 'a procedure = 'a env -> 'a env

(* store procedures *)
type 'a proc_table = ('a procedure) StrMap.t

let do_iinc = function 
  | `Int n -> `Int (n+1)

let iinc x env = 
  let v = do_iinc (IntMap.find x env) in 
  IntMap.add x v env

let do_finc = function 
  | `Float f -> `Float (f +. 1.0)

let finc x env = IntMap.add x (do_finc (IntMap.find x env)) env

(* type error :( *)
let table  = 
  StrMap.add "iinc" (iinc 0)
         (StrMap.add "finc" (finc 1)
                 StrMap.empty)
```

This puzzles me. My "update" is invariant for a concrete type. Shouldn't OCaml be able to figure out that table : `` ([`Float of float ; `Int of int ] procedure) StrMap.t `` ?

I suspect the problem has to do with the variance of map, but I fail to confirm it, since I cannot annotate the type with the concrete polymorphic variants.

Is my idea even feasible in OCaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of this function:

```
let do_finc = function 
  | `Float f -> `Float (f +. 1.0)
```

Is `` [< `Float of float ] -> [> `Float of float ] ``. In other words, it takes as input any variant type that has *at most* a `` `Float `` alternative; i.e., either has a `` `Float `` alternative, or no alternatives at all. It seems to me you want the function to work for variants that have *at least* a `` `Float `` alternative , i.e., a variant that has `` `Float `` and any number of other variants:

```
let do_finc = function 
  | `Float f -> `Float (f +. 1.0)
  | _ -> failwith "wanted a float"
```

If I change `do_iinc` and `do_finc` in this way, the table has a type closer to what you want.

I'm not at all sure that your plan will work, as you might be expecting OCaml to accept type-incorrect programs and complain at runtime. Instead OCaml complains at compile time and you probably have to write your own code to complain at runtime :-) But this might help get past the first problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do, but it looks unsafe to me.

Your `finc 1` does not have type `` [`Float of float ; `Int of int ] procedure `` as you suggest, it has type `` [`Float of float ] procedure `` which is equivalent to `` [`Float of float] IntMap.t -> [`Float of float] IntMap.t ``.

This is because the `do_finc` function, which you apply to a member of your argument `env`, only knows how to handle `` [`Float of float] `` -- it has no case for `` [`Int of int] ``.

If `table` had the type you wanted consider what would happen in the following expression:

```
let f = StrMap.find "finc" table in
let m = IntMap.add 1 (`Int 4) IntMap.empty in
  f m
```

Comment: I would expect the program to throw an "unmatched expression" exception, as for any incomplete pattern. 
The whole idea is to build an inherently unsafe concept (i.e. something like a cast) in OCaml, so unsafe ops are unavoidable.

Comment: The type checking for polymorphic variants deliberately avoids allowing inexhaustive matches, as 99.99% of the time you do not want them. If you do want that then you will have to add your own default case which raises an exception.